# django: Refused to frame 'https://app.powerbi.com/' because an ancestor violates following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: python, django, powerbi, content-security-policy

I am embedding a Power BI report into my django web app. The report uses RLS which I am trying to capture through my CustomUser model's "email" field. I have setup an azure app, I have added my azure principle name to the workspace, I have enabled embed token generation, and I can succesfully get an accesss token and embed token, but when I load the page on my localhost (haven't even tried prod yet), I get the error Refused to frame 'https://app.powerbi.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'.

my view:

```py
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    """Generate our own embed token and pass it to the template
    for the purpose of usable Row Level Security"""

    authority_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + settings.POWER_BI_TENANT_ID
    scopes = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']

    # get access token
    client = msal.PublicClientApplication(settings.POWER_BI_APP_ID, authority=authority_url)
    response = client.acquire_token_by_username_password(settings.POWER_BI_USERNAME, settings.POWER_BI_PASSWORD, scopes=scopes)
    access_token = response["access_token"]

    url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{settings.POWER_BI_WORKSPACE_ID}/reports/{settings.POWER_BI_REPORT_ID}/GenerateToken"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    data = {
        "accessLevel": "View",
        "identities": [
            {
                "username": request.user.email,  # The logged-in user's email
                "roles": ["teamrls"], 
                "datasets": [settings.POWER_BI_DATASET_ID],
            }
        ],
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    embed_token = response.json()["token"]

    # Pass the embed token to your template
    context = {"embed_token": embed_token, "report_id": settings.POWER_BI_REPORT_ID,
               "group_id": settings.POWER_BI_WORKSPACE_ID}
    return render(request, "dataentry/dashboard.html", context)
```

my template:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div id="reportContainer"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/powerbi-client/2.16.5/powerbi.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
    
        var embedConfiguration = {
            type: 'dashboard',
            id: '{{ report_id }}',
            embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/groups/{{ group_id }}/reports/{{ report_id }}',
            accessToken: '{{ embed_token }}',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            permissions: models.Permissions.All,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: true,
                navContentPaneEnabled: true
            }
        };
    
        var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];
        var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, embedConfiguration);
    </script>
```